# Как заменить страницу ошибки в WebView?

Tags: android, webview

Искал искал, но толком ничего не нашёл. Обработка ошибок мне не подходит (т.к я её уже использую). Как заменить стандартную страницу при неудачном подключении к сайту через WebView.

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Раскройте подробнее вот это: `Обработка ошибок мне не подходит (т.к я её уже использую)`. Скорее всего вы либо как-то что-то не то делаете или не добавили необходимой информации. По идее именно через обработку ошибок и стоит делать то, что вам надо.

Comment: Когда я отключаю интернет во время загрузки, эта страница не всплывает. Когда я сразу с отключенным интернетом захожу, появляется текст с ошибкой и стандартная андроид-страница.

Comment: Т.е. у вас onReceivedError метод не вызывается?

Comment: Вызывается, но вместе с ним и страница ошибки. (Это только при перезаходе без интернета)

Comment: Ну, значит при вызове надо как-то отреагировать. У вас в этом вопрос - как отреагировать на ошибку? Можно по разному, например сделать WebView невидимым.

Comment: О, то что нужно. Спасибо, так и сделаю.